# How can I fix `Overfull \hbox` warnings in cleanthesis?

Tags: koma-script, templates, cleanthesis

Cleanthesis produces an overfull hbox for each chapter. (Also when compiling the included sample document.)

`Overfull \hbox (10.94998pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 22--22` (first chapter)

I would like to get rid of these warnings because they clutter my log. The design and layout should not be changed.

#### Attempted solutions

By setting `draft=true` I can see that the problem is somewhere in the header. I think it is something between koma-script and it's header/chapter functions and how cleanthesis uses them  but I couldn't find a good solution.

Changing the width of the mini pages used for the chapter number fixes the hbox but also significantly moves the chapter number to the left. In this example I reduced `0.3\pagewitdh` to `0.27\pagewidth`.

```
\newcommand{\ctchapternumber}[1]{%
    \usekomafont{chapter}%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.27\textwidth}%
        \raggedleft{%
            {\color{ctcolorchapterline}\rule[-5pt]{2pt}{5cm}}%
            \quad%
            {\color{ctcolorchapternum}\fontsize{60}{60}\selectfont#1}%
        }%
    \end{minipage}%
}
```

### MWE ([overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/read/zqzgfrmhjxrw))

```
\documentclass[%
    paper=A4,               % paper size --> A4 is default in Germany
    twoside=true,           % onesite or twoside printing
    openright,              % doublepage cleaning ends up right side
    parskip=half,           % spacing value / method for paragraphs
    chapterprefix=true,     % prefix for chapter marks
    11pt,                   % font size
    headings=normal,        % size of headings
    bibliography=totoc,     % include bib in toc
    listof=totoc,           % include listof entries in toc
    titlepage=on,           % own page for each title page
    captions=tableabove,    % display table captions above the float env
    chapterprefix=false,    % do not display a prefix for chapters
    appendixprefix=false,    % but display a prefix for appendix chapter
    draft=false,            % value for draft version
]{scrreprt}%

\usepackage{cleanthesis}
\usepackage{scrhack}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Aasdf}
    \chapter{Wqwer}
    \chapter{Overfull hbox \#3}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These overfull hbox warnings are caused by the `parskip=half` option and its requirment of  at least 1em free space at the end of the last line of a paragraph (`\parfillskip`). You could ignore these warnings.

To avoid these warnings, you can redefine `\chapterlinesformat` to

```latex
\usepackage{cleanthesis}
\renewcommand{\chapterlinesformat}[3]{%
    \ctchaptertitle{#3}%
    #2%
    \hspace{-1em}%
}
```

Or more generally:

```latex
\usepackage{cleanthesis}
\newlength\savedparfillskip
\newcommand*{\saveparfillskip}[1]{\setlength{\savedparfillskip}{\dimexpr\parfillskip\relax}}
\AddtoDoHook{heading/postinit/chapter}{\saveparfillskip}
\renewcommand{\chapterlinesformat}[3]{%
    \ctchaptertitle{#3}%
    #2%
    \hspace{-\savedparfillskip}%
}
```

This would also work if you switch to `parskip=half+` or `parskip=half*`.

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[%
    %paper=A4,% default
    twoside=true,
    open=right,
    parskip=half,
    %chapterprefix=true,% disabled later by option chapterprefix=false
    %fontsize=11pt,% default
    headings=normal,
    bibliography=totoc,
    listof=totoc,
    titlepage=on,
    captions=tableabove,
    %chapterprefix=false,% default
    %appendixprefix=false,% default if chapterprefix=false 
    %draft=false% default
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{cleanthesis}
\newlength\savedparfillskip
\newcommand*{\saveparfillskip}[1]{\setlength{\savedparfillskip}{\dimexpr\parfillskip\relax}}
\AddtoDoHook{heading/postinit/chapter}{\saveparfillskip}
\renewcommand{\chapterlinesformat}[3]{%
    \ctchaptertitle{#3}%
    #2%
    \hspace{-\savedparfillskip}%
}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Aasdf}
    \chapter{Wqwer}
    \chapter{Overfull hbox \#3}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `diffpdf` can't find the slightest difference, awesome! Now I wonder how you went about debugging this and came up with the solution, but that is probably another question unless you happen to have a link you could just drop here. Anyway, thank you for the solution!